# c# support both multiple and single object operations

Tags: c#, conventions

Say I have the following methods in my code:

```
public bool RemoveItem(Item item)
{ 
   // Logic to remove a single item
}

public bool RemoveItems(List<Item> items)
{
   // Logic for removing multiple items. Running over all items and calling RemoveItem will be inefficient in my case
}

public bool AddItem(Item item)
{
  // Logic for adding single item
}

public bool AddItems(List<Item> items)
{
  // Logic for adding multiple items
}
```

Is there a way to prevent having multiple methods for each operation? I have alot of such methods. I wish to somehow combine each couple of methods into a single one..is there a nice way for doing so?

I can create a list with single item and support only methods that take list as parameter but is seems ugly to me.

How do other people do it?

Comment: Using interfaces, and anonymous objects may help.

Comment: params keyword might work, depending on exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create your methods with `params` keyword:

```
public bool AddItems(params Item[] items)
{
    ...
}

public bool RemoveItems(params Item[] items)
{
   ...
}
```

This allows you call these methods like this:

```
AddItems(item);
AddItems(item1, item2, ...);
or
AddItems(new Item[] { ... });
```

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is right. This is the way it's implemented in the list class, where you have Add() and AddRange()

Comment: Maybe this example specifically should be seperated, but I have many others such as MarkItem/s, Change fields and such methods.

Answer (score 0):

Better to get a list every time no matter if you have one or many items and handle in a single funstion.